# Post to Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, httpclient

I'm trying to use HTTPClient to post an object to my endpoint however I am receiving error message stating:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 415 (Unsupported Media Type).
```

I am using Webjob as a seperate solution to hit my Web Api endpoint. Code for posting as follows:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string path = "http://localhost:15218/api/auth/test";
            var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");
            var res = await client.PostAsync(path, content);
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
```

On StringContent I have tried changing the Encoding to Encoding.UTF32 and Encoding.UTF8 but still receive same message.

**API End Point**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage test(RegisteredEvent s)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

The object I am posting is the same object as the API endpoint Argument takes, but of course I am serialising the object when posting as shown on first snippet code. So not sure why its not hitting.

Comment: Check that the API supports that media type format. It usually accepts Json via the JsonFormatter, but make sure it was not removed during configuration. Make sure that this is not found in your WebApiConfig `config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);`

Comment: Show how you configure the Web API

Comment: Hi, I do not have no formatting in my config file, it is left by default code i.e. Web API route